# error when passing `arma::cube`argument to function using RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am getting the following error when trying to compile using `sourceCpp` from `Rcpp`package:

```
`my path to R/.../Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h`
no matching function for call to 'arma::Cube<double>::Cube(SEXPREC*&)'
```

The object `cube` is the `armadillo` equivalent of an `array` in `R`.

**EDIT**: Note that the problem seems to be that the function can't accept a `arma::cube` object as an argument. If we change `arma::cube B`by `arma::mat B`it does work:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;

//  [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube ssmooth(arma::mat  A, 
                   arma::cube B) {

int ns = A.n_rows;    
int nk = A.n_cols;    
int np = B.n_rows;    

arma::mat C = zeros<mat>(nk, ns);
arma::cube D = zeros<cube>(nk, nk, ns);

return D;

}
```

I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 4):

A basic example works:

```
R> cppFunction("arma::cube getCube(int n) { arma::cube a(n,n,n);\
                    a.zeros(); return a; }", depends="RcppArmadillo")
R> getCube(2)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

R>
```

so either you are doing something wrong or your installation is off.

Comment: Thanks, I get the error in both Windows and Debian but I will check my code again.

Comment: the error seems to be that the function won't accept the object `cube` as an argument but will accept `mat` for instance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. For some reason it won't accept `arma::cube` as an argument. I updated Rcpp and RcppArmadillo to versions 0.12.1 and 0.6.100.0.0 respectively, and the problem persists. I'm working under ubuntu 14.04, g++ 4.8.4 and R 3.2.2

Comment: Your example works fine, the problem is when you have something like `arma::cube cubeinout(arma::cube x) {
  return x;
}`. I've tried both, cppFunction and sourceCpp and still get the same error `Exporter.h:31:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘arma::Cube<double>::Cube(SEXPREC*&)’
       Exporter( SEXP x ) : t(x){}`.

Comment: RIght.  The other two answers address that too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The problem seems to be related to the combination "Rcpp::export" and cube as an argument of the exported function. My guess is that the converter from sexp to cube may not be implemented yet (no pun intended ;-)). (Or we are both missing something...).

Workaround when you want to have an arma::cube argument in a Rcpp::export function: get it first as a NumericVector and simply create the cube afterward...

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;

//  [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube ssmooth(arma::mat  A, 
                   NumericVector B_) {
  IntegerVector dimB=B_.attr("dim");
  arma::cube B(B_.begin(), dimB[0], dimB[1], dimB[2]);

  //(rest of your code unchanged...)
  int ns = A.n_rows;    
  int nk = A.n_cols;    
  int np = B.n_rows;    

  arma::mat C = zeros<mat>(nk, ns);
  arma::cube D = zeros<cube>(nk, nk, ns);

  return D;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code fails because implicitly it tries to do casting like this:

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
cube return_thing(SEXP thing1){
  cube thing2 = as<cube>(thing1);
  return thing2;
}


/***R
thing <- 1:8
dim(thing) <- c(2, 2, 2)
return_thing(thing)
*/
```

which doesn't work, whereas it works for matrices:

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

//[[Rcpp::export]]
mat return_thing(SEXP thing1){
  mat thing2 = as<mat>(thing1);
  return thing2;
}


/***R
thing <- 1:4
dim(thing) <- c(2, 2)
return_thing(thing)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read and return an arma cube with the following function :

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube return_cube(arma::cube X)
{
  return(X);
}
```

For example, I obtain the following result when I run the following in **R** :

```
my_cube <- array(data = rnorm(5 * 3 * 2), dim = c(5,3, 2))
return_cube(my_cube)
, , 1

          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.4815994  1.0863765  0.3278728
[2,] 1.4138699 -0.7809922  0.8341867
[3,] 0.6555752 -0.2708001  0.7701501
[4,] 1.1447104 -1.4064894 -0.2653888
[5,] 1.5972670  1.8368235 -2.2814959

, , 2

             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.485091067  1.1826162 -0.3524851
[2,]  0.227652584  0.3005968 -0.6079604
[3,] -0.147653664  1.3463318 -1.2238623
[4,]  0.067090580 -0.8982740 -0.8903684
[5,]  0.006421618 -1.7156955 -1.2813880
```